Is it possible to make a Blinking LED with only 1 LED
For a school homework of mine, I have to make a Blinking LED. I see tutorials on youtube for 2 LEDs (and have also made the same), but tutorials for 1 LED seem to be misleading and a lot of comments were claiming that making it with 1 LED is impossible. Is this true? If it isn't, can someone please tell me how I can do this?
Many thanks

Which circuit you are talking about? Of course you can make a one-LED blinker. Proof : have you ever seen one LED that blinks even if there is no other LED? The details will define how to blink it.

In a multi-LED blinker, you can always replace the unwanted LEDs with just plain silicon diodes. Some blinkers are sensitive to the voltage drop across the LED to an extent, so several diodes in series may be needed to substitute for a LED.
A LED has an operating forward voltage broadly between 1V and 3V, let’s say. A silicon rectifier has a forward voltage of 0.7V.
But I wouldn’t worry about putting several diodes in series to replace a LED. Start with a single diode in place of the LED and most blinkers will work fine. If it doesn’t, flip the diode around since it’s likely put in “backwards” relative to the LED. If that doesn’t help then double check for correct polarity and add one or two diodes in series. Any circuit I can think of will work that way.
As for it being impossible: did they really never see just a single LED blinking?! The mind boggles.
The silicon diode and its series resistor or current source will be wasting power just as the LED did - just without producing visible light. So you can try increasing the series resistor to decrease this current. It depends on the rest of the circuit whether it will work with such a change or not.
A simple single-LED blinker uses Schmitt-trigger-input CMOS gates like CD4093 or CD40106. I can draw a schematic if you’d like.

Any MCU, pretty much, will have a 'blink LED' program as an example. It's the 'Hello, world' of the embedded world.
Here's the compilation log of a simple example for the ESP32 (an inexpensive 32-bit processor) that uses an RTOS to time the LED blinks.

In a very small MCU, just blinking an LED might be a handful of instructions adding up to 20 or 30 bytes. A small OTP 8-bit processor solution would comparable to a '555' analog solution, with better precision and lower parts count.
